# How to remove issue with extra white space using CSS or HTML?

Tags: html, css, prettier

I am developing application in Nuxt/Vue and my texts are coming from i18n, some of the texts have got regex line breaks inside `\n` and if I want to display this correctly I am forced to use CSS `white-space: pre-line` property but when I do so every enter created during formating code by prettier adds me extra line before any element (only spans are working properly) but in this case I need `<h4>` element.

```
<h4>
  Lorem ipsum sit dolores
</h4>

<h4>Lorem ipsum sit dolores</h4>
```

Is there any chance to remove this extra white space from rendering and have fully working `white-space: pre-line` property?

**EDIT**

1. I know this works (I've added it to example):

`<h4>Lorem Ipsum sit Dolores</h4>`

2. I am forced to use `pre-line` because some of texts are coming from BE and they have some break lines inside
3. Prettier doesn't allow me to format it in one line and I cannot disable prettier. Prettier forwards me the text to the new line automatically

```css
h4 {
  border: 1px solid goldenrod;
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<h4>
  Lorem ipsum sit dolores
</h4>

<h4>Lorem ipsum sit dolores</h4>
```

Comment: Your HTML is being formatted via prettier to be `<h4>\nLorem ipsum sit dolores\n</h4>`, right? Can you clarify how you want this to be output? How/why are you being forced to use `white-space: pre-line`?

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones see the description once more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1: You can make [prettier ignore](https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html) that specific tag like this:

```
<!-- prettier-ignore -->
<h4>Lorem ipsum sit dolores</h4>
```

Solution 2: Another hacky way that could possibly work (untested). I think prettier won't align the  tag in this case.

```css
h4 {
  white-space: pre-line;
  border: 1px solid goldenrod;
}

h4::after {
  content: "This is a title";
}
```

```html
<h4></h4>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, but I am still curious if there is any html/css workaround for this

Comment: @Freestyle09 I am no expert in css, but I think there doesn't exist a way to remove newline characters with css.

Comment: I need SEO so I cannot insert text with CSS

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution. Simply if you don't want to disable prettier you can wrap your text with span and everything works perfect.

```css
h4 {
  border: 1px solid goldenrod;
}
h4 span {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<h4>
  <span>Lorem ipsum sit dolores</span>
</h4>

<h4>Lorem ipsum sit dolores</h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into an issue recently where there was extra white space added to a list and it's anchor elements...

no white space:

```
<ul>
<li><a>link</a><span>icon</span></li>
</ul>
```

white space:

```
<ul>
<li>

  <a>link</a>

  <span>icon</span>

</li>
</ul>
```

In the application, a pseudo selector adds a bullet to each list element, but the bullet spacing is inconsistent between each list that has extra white space versus no extra white space. This creates a problem when trying to style the list content and bullet especially during text wrapping.

To fix, I displayed each li as a flex object and the white space gets removed without needing to remove it from the actual HTML. Note, you can also try using display: table; but it only works in Chrome and not Firefox.

```
ul li {
display: flex;
}
```

See code demo. Hope this helps.

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  list-style: none;
  margin: .5em 0;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 140px;
}

ul li {
  margin: 5px 0 5px 15px;
}

ul li::before {
  content:"\00BB" !important;
  margin-left: -12px;
}

ul li a {
  color: #006699;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

ul.removewhitespace li {
  display: flex;
  width: min-content;
}

ul.removewhitespace li span {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 1 100%;
  align-self: end;
  margin-left: -.1em;
}

.icon-check {
  content: "";
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' fill='currentColor' class='bi bi-check-circle-fill' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3E%3Cpath d='M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0zm-3.97-3.03a.75.75 0 0 0-1.08.022L7.477 9.417 5.384 7.323a.75.75 0 0 0-1.06 1.06L6.97 11.03a.75.75 0 0 0 1.079-.02l3.992-4.99a.75.75 0 0 0-.01-1.05z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") no-repeat center 0;
  background-size: auto;
  background-size: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<ul class="removewhitespace">
<li>
&nbsp;
<a href="#">Remove whitespace in this list with flex.</a><span class="icon-check"></span></li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li>
&nbsp;
<a href="#">Leave the whitespace in this list as is.</a><span class="icon-check"></span></li>
</ul>
```